# How to prove Page's theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, group-theory

### Question Statement:

Page's theorem in ["Jerusalem Lectures on Black Holes and Quantum Information"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231) is stated as (eq (5.12), page 51):

For any bipartite Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$,

$$\int dU \|\rho_A(U)-\frac{I_A}{|A|}\|_1\leq \sqrt{\frac{|A|^2-1}{|A||B|+1}},$$

where $U$ is chosen from the group invariant Haar measure used to randomize a pure state $\left|\psi_0\right>$ such that $\left|\psi\right>=U\left|\psi_0\right>$, $\rho_A$ is the corresponding density operator of the subsystem A and $L_1$ and $L_2$ trace norms are defined for an operator $M$:

$$\|M\|_1\equiv tr\sqrt{M^{\dagger}M}     \quad\& \quad\|M\|_2\equiv\sqrt{trM^{\dagger}M}.$$

These norms satisfy the inequality

$$\|M\|_2\leq\|M\|_1\leq\sqrt{N}\|M\|_2. \qquad \text{($N$ is the dimensionality of the Hilbert space.)}$$

### Attempt:

\begin{align}
\left(\int dU \|\rho_A-\frac{I_A}{|A|}\|_1\right)^2 &\leq\int dU\left(\|\rho_A(U)-\frac{I_A}{|A|}\|_1\right)^2  \text{(Jensen's inequality)}\\
  &\leq|A|\int dU \left(\|\rho_A(U)-\frac{I_A}{|A|}\|_2\right)^2  \text{(From the inequality stated above)}
\end{align}

Now I need to solve this integral.

---

The notes mention that the following might be helpful:

$$\int dU=1$$

$$\int dU U_{ij} U^{\dagger}_{kl}=\frac{1}{N}\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}$$

$$\int dU U_{ij}U_{kl}U^{\dagger}_{mn}U^{\dagger}_{op}=\frac{1}{N^2-1}\left(\delta_{in}\delta_{kp}\delta_{jm}\delta_{lo}+\delta_{ip}\delta_{kn}\delta_{jo}\delta_{lm}\right)-\frac{1}{N\left(N^2-1\right)}\left(\delta_{in}\delta_{kp}\delta_{jo}\delta_{lm}+\delta_{in}\delta_{kn}\delta_{jm}\delta_{lo}\right)$$

Comment: What is $\rho_A(U)$?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch  It is the reduced density operator on system $A$. If a pure state is $\left|\psi_0\right>$on $H_A\otimes H_B$, $U$ is used to produce a random pure state $\left|\psi\right>$ such that $\left|\psi\right>=U\left|\psi_0\right>$. Hence, the reduced density operator is dependent on $U$.

Comment: Do you mind editing the post accordingly, so it is complete?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you can find the proof in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407049 (and probably much stronger bounds)

Comment: Reference [15] in said paper: [S. K. Foong and S. Kanno, *Proof of Page’s conjecture on the average entropy of a subsystem.* Phys. Rev. Lett. 72, 1148 (1994)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.72.1148)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Edited the question.

Comment: @Reshad i just read this again and realized that how to use this formula to compute the integral might have been your main question. if you're still stuck on this i'm happy to expand my answer below

Comment: @4xion yes indeed! I am stuck as I have not been able to convert the trace of the reduced density matrix squared in terms of U. If you can expand your answer, it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! The first two steps are using Jensen's and upper bounding in terms of the 2-norm. You now want to write out the 2-norm and then compute the Haar integral. After the first step, you should find:
$$
\big\|\rho_A(U) - I_A/|A|\big\|_2^2 = {\rm tr}\big(\rho_A(U)^2\big) - 1/|A|
$$
and then integrate the purity using the 2nd moment formula (the last integral expression you wrote with two $U$'s and two $U^\dagger$'s) to find the bound above.

(small clarification: Page's theorem is really about the von Neumann entropy of a random state being close to maximal. He conjectured an [exact expression](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9305007), which was [later](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601132) [proven](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.72.1148). But this is closely related to what you're trying to prove above, that subsystems of random states look very close to maximally mixed.)