# Integration with respect to Haar measure and reduced density matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-gravity, density-operator

Consider a bipartite system $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$, with $|A|,|B|>>1$ and not necceserly $|A|=|B|$.

Following *[Jerusalem Lectures on Black Holes and Quantum Information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231)* (eq. 5.8) we can define a *random* pure state by
$$
|\psi(U)\rangle \equiv U\left|\psi_{0}\right\rangle,
$$
where $U$ is a random unitary matrix taken from a group invariant Haar measure $U(N)$. Following the reference, one can consider a reduced density matrix (corresponding to the above pure state) by tracing out $B$
$$\rho_{A}(U)=\text{Tr}_B \rho(U). $$
I want to calculate the following quantity
$$
\int \mathrm{d}U \ \text{Tr}\rho_{A}^2(U).
$$
And I know useful identities
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int d U U_{i j} U_{k l}^{\dagger}=& \frac{1}{N} \delta_{i l} \delta_{j k} \\
\int d U U_{i j} U_{k l} U_{m n}^{\dagger} U_{o p}^{\dagger}=& \frac{1}{N^{2}-1}\left(\delta_{i n} \delta_{k p} \delta_{j m} \delta_{l o}+\delta_{i p} \delta_{k n} \delta_{j o} \delta_{l m}\right) \\
&-\frac{1}{N\left(N^{2}-1\right)}\left(\delta_{i n} \delta_{k p} \delta_{j o} \delta_{l m}+\delta_{i p} \delta_{k n} \delta_{j m} \delta_{l o}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
**My attempt**
$$
\int \mathrm{d}U \ \text{Tr}\rho_{A}^2(U) = \int \mathrm{d}U \text{Tr}(U \rho_{A} U^\dagger U \rho_{A} U^\dagger) = \int \mathrm{d}U \text{Tr}(U \rho_{A} \rho_{A} U^\dagger)=
$$

$$
 = \int \mathrm{d}U( U_{ab}(\rho_A)_{bc}(\rho_A)_{cd}U_{da}) =(\rho_A)_{bc}(\rho_A)_{cd} \int \mathrm{d}U (U_{ab}U_{da}) =(\rho_A)_{bc}(\rho_A)_{cd} \frac{1}{N}\delta_{aa}\delta_{bd}=
$$
$$
= (\rho_A)_{dc}(\rho_A)_{cd} \frac{|A|}{|A||B|}
$$
I believe that my calculation is wrong because I should have obtained the object which depends only on |A| and |B| at the end of the day. Probably my interpretation of $\rho_A (U)= U\rho_A U^\dagger$ is invalid. Could someone clarify it to me or give some hints on how to properly do this calculation?

Comment: What on earth is rho_A? (Not rho_A(U).)

Comment: Ok, I thought that for $\rho = |\psi_0\rangle\langle \psi_0|$ the following holds $\text{Tr}_B U \rho U^\dagger = U \rho_A U^\dagger $. Now I think that this is not true since dimensions are different after tracing

Comment: Indeed. _______

Comment: Is it correct to write without loss of generality $U=U^A\otimes U^B$ and then $ U\rho U^\dagger = U^A_{ai}|\psi_i\rangle U^B_{bj}|\varphi_j\rangle\langle\varphi_{j^{'}}|U^B_{j^{'}b^{'}}\langle\psi_{i^{'}}|U^A_{i^{'}a^{'}} $?

Comment: In the second equation: Hard to say, given that you didn't define the objects on the right side, nor whether you are summing over anything (and what). But in the first equation: No, this is plain wrong. You are loosing *all* generality.

Comment: But does the link on the right: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/564824/ help?

Comment: Basically what I want to calculate is $\operatorname{tr}\left(\rho_{A}(U)^{2}\right)$ from this link. The author of the answer didn't tell how exactly do this

Comment: Btw, concerning $U=U^{A} \otimes U^{B}$, does the group invariance of the Haar measure preserve the generality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider each index to $U_{ij}$ to be a double index: $i=(i_A,i_B)$, and $j=(j_A,j_B)$. We can define the Haar-random state by $\lvert\psi\rangle = U\lvert0\rangle$, that is, $\lvert\psi\rangle = \sum U_{(i_A,i_B),(0,0)}\lvert i_A,i_B\rangle$. Then,
$$
\mathrm{tr}(\rho_A(U)^2) = 
\sum U_{(i_A,i_B),(0,0)}U^\dagger_{(0,0),(j_A,i_B)}
U_{(j_A,k_B),(0,0)}U^\dagger_{(0,0),(i_A,k_B)}\ .
$$
Then, the integral can be solved using the second of the "helpful formulas".

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Could you clarify the definition of $|\psi\rangle$? I guess that you are using the Schmidt decomposition, namely $|0\rangle = |i_A=0, i_B=0\rangle$. If yes, please tell me why this correct, because it seems to me that we can write it in that way (just one element of the total general sum) only for separable states.

Comment: @nabzdyczony Nope. It is just the definition you give for $\vert\psi\rangle$ with $\vert\psi_0\rangle = \vert0\rangle\vert0\rangle$ (in the given partition of the system). But it does not matter, you will get the same distribution of states $\vert\psi\rangle$ for *any* choice of $\psi_0$. (That's the point of the Haar measure!) And, indeed, you could replace the $(0,0)$ by whatever you like. It might just complicate the equations if it is not a basis state.

Comment: Why are there terms like $(j_A,i_B)$? It should be $(j_A,j_B)$ right?

Comment: Is it because we should do $\rho_{A}(U)=\text{Tr}_B \rho(U).$

Comment: Also what indices are you summing? The dimensionality of A indices is $|A|$ and for B it is $|B|$.

Comment: Never mind I understood, you are summing over all the indices.