# How to derive the probability distribution of reduced density matrix eigenvalues for randomly chosen pure states in Page's theorem?

Tags: quantum-information, mathematical-physics, probability, research-level, ads-cft

**Motivation** 
I am trying to reproduce the proof in Page's theorem as conjectured in the seminal paper [Average Entropy of a Subsystem by Don N. Page](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9305007). It is crucial in various resolutions of black hole information paradox involving the Page curve.

**The Problem** 
In the original paper, Don Page is trying to derive an expression for coarse grained entropy $S_{mn}=\langle S_A \rangle$ where $S_A$ is the [Von-Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) associated with a system $A$ with Hilbert space dimension $m$, where the average is taken respect to the unitary invariant Haar measure on the space of unitary vectors in the $mn$ dimensional Hilbert space of the total system. For the calculation he was was led to consider the probability distribution of the eigenvalues
of the reduced density matrix $\rho_A$ for the random pure states $\rho$ of the entire system. He used $$P(p_1,p_2,...,p_m)=N~\delta(1-\sum_{i=1}^m p_i) \prod_{1\le i\le j \le m} (p_i-p_j)^2 \prod_{k=1}^m p_k^{n-m} dp_k \tag{1}$$ in an intermediate step. This was partially derived in an earlier paper by [Lloyd and Pagels](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491688900942) and completed in a "private communication" between Page and Lloyds. I am unable to derive the above expression having no access to the private communication (obviously!) and also unable to salvage some help from the seemingly cryptic Lloyd-Pagels paper.

**Additional Information and my Question**

Page's conjecture (now often called Page's theorem) was completed in: 
i. [Average entropy of a subsytem by Sidhhartha Sen](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601132) (which one can refer to for an extremely short review of Page's work) 
ii. [Simple proof of Page's conjecture on the average entropy of a subsystem by Sanchez Ruiz](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.52.5653) 
iii. [Proof of Page's Conjecture on the Average Entropy of a Subsystem by Foong and Kanno](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.72.1148)

However, each of this assumed the step I am having difficulty in because the authors focussed in the calculation of an integral which Page could not perform for generic cases in his paper. So, How to derive the probability distribution of reduced density matrix eigenvalues for randomly chosen pure states which is given in eq. ($1$) above?

**P.S.** I am aware of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564824/how-to-prove-pages-theorem) Q/A which also asks for intermediate steps in derivation of Page theorem but the form of the theorem given there is highly different---I believe I am asking a distinct question.